# SELECT bigint[] from table, then lookup each item from bigint[] in another table

Tags: c#, postgresql, subquery

I have two tables:

PROJECT that contains the two columns - PROJECTNAME (text) and HOSTS (bigint[])

[image: PROJECT Table]

HOST that contains the three columns HOSTID (bigint) and IP (inet) and HOSTNAME (text)

[image: HOST Table]

I wish to write a single query that does the following:

```
SELECT hosts 
FROM project
WHERE projectname = 'Project test'
```

then for each bigint in HOSTS I wish to do something like this:

```
FOREACH hostid in HOSTS(bigint[])
SELECT x,y,x FROM HOST WHERE IP <<=inet '10.10.10.0/20'
```

I'm currently doing this in an inefficient way with multiple separate queries. I'd really like to understand how to combine them into one succinct query.

Thanks, I'm just keen to better understand how to build these queries.

Comment: I would first fix the data model and get rid of the array. Use a proper many to many relation ship using an additional table. A simple JOIN to connect the different tables and records can solve your problem.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join using the ANY operator:

```
SELECT h.hostid, h.ip, h.hostname
FROM project p
  JOIN hosts h on h.hostid = ANY(p.hosts)
WHERE p.projectname = 'Project test'
  AND h.ip <<= inet '10.10.10.0/20';
```

Comment: Thank you. I realise my tables could be better - but I just wanted to know how it would be done, if it had to be that way.